# Saving changes in Developer Tools is not working

Tags: google-chrome

I am opening a html file with Chrome, Inspect Element on the page and change something.
Then I save it to the same or another file and when I open it, it's unchanged.
I do not understand why? I am doing something wrong ?
My goal is to modify a few values in a table and save the changes to the html file.

Comment: You can not save change as per my information, correct me if I am wrong. More information here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/UbmrXYETvU0

Comment: I also read this where it says that it can be done [http://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/](http://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/)

Comment: It also says you can not edit html files but JS files only 2nd para

Comment: Yes I missed that, thanks. Do you know another way to do this ?

Comment: After changes, Go to HTML node (or Root node in Item Inspector). Hit F2 or right click -> Edit as HTML and Select all text (Ctrl+A) Copy (Ctrl+C) and then save using notepad or any IDE

Comment: mark the answer as solution, if it solved your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not save [HTML or CSS changes directly using Item Inspector](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/UbmrXYETvU0) , but only JS changes as explained on [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/). If you still want to save HTML changes following dirty steps:

- Make your changes
- Go to HTML node (or Root node in Item Inspector).
- Hit F2 or right click -> Edit as HTML  Select all text (Ctrl+A) and
- Copy (Ctrl+C)  Save using notepad or any IDE